# Scopes in asp.net?

Tags: java, asp.net

In `asp.net`, is there something similar to the different scopes in `JavaEE`?
What are the equivalents for:

- Request-Scope
- Session-Scope
- Application-Scope

Or maybe someone can explain me why it's handled different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaEE you specify the scope of a bean (in a config file or via annotations)
In .NET there some "ready" objects that you can use, by default all "beans" are request-scoped.

For example, if you want to set an object scope to be Session-scope, you can use the [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) object to store it, like `Session["CurrentUser"] = user;`,  it can hold any object data type
It's the same for [Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178594%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) , it is shared across all the users on the site.

You can find more details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET has the same: Application, Session and Request. Read more here: [Page and Application Context in ASP.NET Web Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swe97x0b%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

What do you mean by different? I think they are quite similar.